# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error for FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

for my BottomNavigator Bar I am using Getx navigation like this:

```
else if (selectedPage == 3) {
   
      Get.to(VideoViewDetail(id: '1465'));
```

but I am getting following error:

The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#03585):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804119/9997212), use

```
Future.microtask(() => Get.to(VideoViewDetail(id: '1465')));
```